# AEM - How to return page information in JSON format

Tags: aem

I need to display the title and name of all child and grand child pages from given path in JSON format. Please provide the implementation.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where you have stuck?

Comment: SO is for programming questions. "Please provide the implementation" is not a question, it's a coding request.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to try something yourself, then you call for help, not the complete solution!anyway there are couple of solution down there.

According to [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/pageinfo.html) here you can implement page information in JSON format:

```
package com.adobe.example;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.ReferenceCardinality;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;

import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject;

import com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page;
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageInfoProvider;

@Component(metatype = false)
@Properties({
    @Property(name="service.description", value="Returns the public URL of a resource.")
})
@Service
public class PageUrlInfoProvider implements PageInfoProvider {


    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_UNARY)
    private com.day.cq.commons.Externalizer externalizer;

    private String fetchExternalUrl(ResourceResolver rr, String path) {
        return externalizer.publishLink(rr, path);
    }

    public void updatePageInfo(SlingHttpServletRequest request, JSONObject info, Resource resource)
            throws JSONException {

        Page page = resource.adaptTo(Page.class);
        JSONObject urlinfo = new JSONObject();
        urlinfo.put("publishURL", fetchExternalUrl(null,page.getPath()));
        info.put("URLs",urlinfo);
    }
}
```

Or you may try this [Page](http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2015/12/converting-aem-sling-resources-to-json) for solution

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below link which may be useful:
http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2015/12/converting-aem-sling-resources-to-json.

Apart from the above solution you also use recursive level to get the data in the JSON format for example /content/we-retail/language-masters/en.{**placeholder**}.json

replace the placeholder with the level of nodes you want to print and return back the JSON wherever needed.

To know more about the rendering data in different formats,
Refer: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/rendering-content-default-get-servlets.html